# Concatenate multiple pairs of files

Tags: cat

I have 120 pairs of files I would like to concatenate.
I have the list of pair of files and the proposed merged file name in a tab delimited file as follows

```
Filelist.txt

/filepath/1_first.fasta /filepath/1_second.fasta > /filepath/1_merged.fasta

/filepath/2_first.fasta /filepath/2_second.fasta > /filepath/2_merged.fasta

/filepath/3_first.fasta /filepath/3_second.fasta > /filepath/3_merged.fasta 

/filepath/4_first.fasta /filepath/4_second.fasta > /filepath/4_merged.fasta
```

I was trying:

```
$cat Filelist.txt | perl -ne 'chomp;system("cat $_;")'
```

with the idea of handling the Filelist.txt line by line and using the cat command on the line which for the first line should be...

```
/filepath/1_first.fasta /filepath/1_second.fasta > /filepath/1_merged.fasta
```

If I just have one pair and a single line in the Filelist.txt it works fine but with multiple lines I just get ..

```
/filepath/2_first.fasta: No such file or directory
```

$

Any clues why this might not be working for every single line?
Or an alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this:

```
sed -e 's/^/cat /' Filelist.txt | bash
```

Assuming your `Filelist.txt` is really formatted that way (i.e. actually has the redirection included as shown). Maybe try the above without the `| bash` part first and inspect the output to make sure it looks like the right commands you want to run.

Comment: for /filepath/1_first.fastq.gz /filepath/1_second.fastqz > /filepath/1_merged_fastq.gz without bash to test it I get filepath/1_first.fastq.gz./filepath/1_second.fastqzf>stq.gz /filepath/1_merged_fastq.gzfastq.gz almost there but not quite? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: With output like that, I'm guessing your input file doesn't really look like what is posted above. The only thing the above command should do (without the `| bash`) part, is put `cat ` at the beginning of each line. Unless you have some wonky line ending issues going on or something... Was that `Filelist.txt` created on a Windows or Mac system, maybe?

Comment: Yes on a Mac, I've gone through it on nano in the terminal and checked that all separations are tabs and all line endings are just newlines and its all in the exact order I posted, below is two lines copy and pasted out of my actual Filelist.txt, thanks again for looking at this

Comment: /Volumes/resource/sequence_files/130412_RUN15/Fastqgz/GSK-0051_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  /Volumes/resource/sequence_files/130404_RUN14/Fastqgz/GSK-0051_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz > /Volumes/resource/sequence_files/merged_fastqs/GSK_0051R1_merged
/Volumes/resource/sequence_files/130412_RUN15/Fastqgz/GSK-0051_S5_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  /Volumes/resource/sequence_files/130404_RUN14/Fastqgz/GSK-0051_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz >       /Volumes/resource/sequence_files/merged_fastqs/GSK_0051R2_merged

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat * > merged_file
```

This will CAT all files in the directory and the output will be outputted into the merged_file.

Comment: I need the 120 pairs to have 120 separate merged outputs.